# Page count disappears after changing margins

Tags: margins, page-numbering, geometry

I changed margins in my document midway to adjust for large figures, but at that point my page count disappeared altogether. Here is the code snippet :

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage[margin=0.95in]{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\begin{document}
\section{Chapter 1}
\newpage\null
\section{Chapter 2}
\newpage\null

\newgeometry{left=3cm,bottom=0.1cm,top=2cm}
\section{Large figures}
\hspace{-2cm}\vspace{-5cm}\includegraphics[page = 1,scale = 0.9,angle=90]{fig1.pdf}

\hspace{-3cm}\vspace{-5cm}\includegraphics[page = 2,scale = 0.9,angle=90]{fig2.pdf}

\hspace{-2cm}\vspace{-5cm}\includegraphics[page = 3,scale = 0.9,angle=90]{fig3.pdf}
\restoregeometry % restore back previous settings
\newpage\null
\section{Chapter End}
\end{document}
```

I used `showframe` option to see how I changed the frames, and could see that for the figures that I used, the page number frame had disappeared. But for the remaining pages, it was back. However, there was still no page number on those pages.

Comment: The bottom margin is too small, the page number is pushed below the paper edge. If you want to keep the space for the footer, use the `includefoot` option. Otherwise this is the space between the text area and the bottom of the paper, not between the footer and the bottom of the paper.

`\newgeometry{includefoot,left=3cm,bottom=0.1cm,top=2cm}`

Comment: That worked perfectly. For some reason though, a blank page is created at `\newgeometry` command. That is, after the `\newpage\null` command, an additional page is created.

Comment: @imranal ``\newgeometry`` always creates a page break. It is part of the command.

Comment: @Dan I tried  `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` but it could not remove the page break. Don't understand why someone found it necessary to add a blank page for simply adjusting margins through a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following post happens to be relevant for this problem :

[How to change geometry and remove page number from page containing one large figure only without automatically inserted blank page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/293972/how-to-change-geometry-and-remove-page-number-from-page-containing-one-large-fig)

The answer was answered as a comment :

> Instead of the newgeometry and afterpage stuff, use `\includepdf`

Here is a minimal code example :

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,onecolumn]{article}

\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[margin=0.95in]{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\begin{document}
\section{Chapter 1}
\newpage\null
\section{Chapter 2}
\newpage\null

\section{Large figures}
\includepdf[page = 1,scale = 0.9,angle=90]{page1.pdf}
\includepdf[page = 2,scale = 0.9,angle=90]{page2.pdf}
\includepdf[page = 3,scale = 0.9,angle=90]{page3.pdf}

\newpage\null
\section{Chapter End}

\end{document}
```